# CSS hover styling on just the border of an object?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, themes

I'm having an issue customizing the CSS of some button widgets that came with a WordPress theme I'm running.  I grabbed a quick screen capture video of what's happening because it's hard to describe.

Video Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mYvOtAjz-0QnJYV3_nGYXnFoRpsRdVo_

The CSS I have applied on the buttons:

```
.lc_button {
    height: 100px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    border: 1px solid #dd3333 !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.lc_button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #dd3333 !important;
    color: #151515 !important;
}

.lc_button a:hover {
    color: #151515 !important;
}
```

Any idea what I have to do to get the inside to stay visible no matter where the cusror is at inside the button?

Thanks

Comment: If the video is showing exactly what you're facing then due to the fading effect I suspect there's more to this than just the css you've posted.  Can you supply the html as well?

Comment: please share your html file also

Comment: I've attached two answers in Code Snippet...Check both of it and update me...

Comment: Did u got the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to solve your problem. I am successful. You can use this code of mine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="lc_button">
    <a href="#">Watch video</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .lc_button a {
        display: block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #000000;
        border-radius: 5%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: 0.3s;
        background-color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    .lc_button a:before {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 5%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        content: "";
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid red;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .lc_button a:hover:before {
        border: 4px solid red;
    }
    .lc_button a:hover {
        color: #151515 !important;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```css
.lc_button a {
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #000000;
      border-radius: 5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      transition: 0.3s;
      background-color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
  }
  .lc_button a:before {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 5%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   content: "";
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid red;
   transition: 0.3s;
  }
  .lc_button a:hover:before {
     border: 4px solid red;
  }
  .lc_button a:hover {
      color: #151515 !important;
      background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="lc_button">
    <a href="#">Watch video</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The .css you've provided seems fully functional, and customizable. (aka, not broken, works fine).

The whole .css and the .html might shed some light on things without any "major alterations".

```css
.lc_button {
    height: 100px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    border: 1px solid #dd3333 !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5%;
}
.lc_button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #0000ff !important;
    color: #00ff00 !important;
}
.lc_button a:hover {
    color: #151515 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="lc_button">Test</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've shared the code snippet..I think this will help you to solve the problem...

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f54785;
}
.container{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
button{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 30px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
}
span{
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 80px;
}
button::before, button::after{
  content:"";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}

span::before, span::after{
  content:"";
  width:2px;
  height:0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  background: #fff;
}
button:hover::before, button:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
button:hover span::before, button:hover span::after{
  height: 100%;
}
.btn-1::after{
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.btn-1 span::after{
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.btn-1::before{
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.btn-1 span::before{
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-1"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to solve the problem...

```css
button {
    height: 100px !important;
    width: 200px !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    border: 1px solid #dd3333 !important;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #dd3333 !important;
    color: #151515 !important;
}

button a:hover {
    color: #151515 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="lc_button"><span>Hover Me</span></button>
  </div>
```